# .htaccess Redirect 301 to mobile directory - too many redirects ERROR

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile

Hey there StackOverflow Community, i searched a lot on stackoverflow to fix my "too many redirect" Error.
But couldn't find anything that helps. I want to redirect to a mobile directory via .htaccess and the UserAgent Condition. Found a high voted Solution that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirect itself works great but its seems like the mobile browsers add /mobile in a loop so the URL grows into something like http://mysite.com/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile till i get an Error "couldn't open site because of too many redirects".

My complete .htaccess looks like this:

```
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in Advance, Lucas Tito

Comment: Happened the same many times. Is it possible that the htaccess is inside some folder into http://mysite.com/mobile ? This would be a recursive redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `RewriteRule` with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!mobile/).*)$ /mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Problem is that you're unconditionally prefixing `/mobile/` before any URL even ones that already start with `/mobile/`.

Comment: Note: if using intern links in /mobile documents they must point to documents within this folder otherwise the redirect loop error appears again. I tried to link to a movie file ../src/video.mp4 for example.

Comment: @TITO: Hope this answer solves your posted problem. If in case you run into a new problem then feel free to post a new question with a link to this one so that problem can be addressed independently.